# Create fake testing response for Google Maps API

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am testing some code that hits the Google Maps API and, of course, I don't actually want to hit their API. There are essentially 2 things that I want to test for...

1. If I pass a valid address, I receive a response object with the
   `lat` and `lng` attributes.
2. If I pass an invalid address, I receive
   a response object with an `error` attribute.

Now, the test is working when I hit their API but as I said, I want to basically hit a fake API so my tests are not dependent on Google's API.

What is a good way to do this that would actually test my code? I don't want to do something just for the sake of having a passing test. Rather, I want it to be an actual test.

Here is one of my test cases that looks for an error in the response:

```
/** @test */
function an_error_attribute_is_returned_when_there_are_no_results()
{
    $origin = '';
    $destination = '';
    $request = new GetDistanceRequest($origin, $destination);

    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('error', $request->receive());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no replacement for an integration test between your application and google maps.

You could easily unit test that your application handles the data object returned by google maps on a successful request, and that your code can handle an error response from google maps.  You could copy the response returned from each of those requests, save it as a file, and provide it to your code as a fixture.  The problem with this is that google api can get out of sync with your test data.  Your tests could be passing, then when you go to push your application they could change their api, and your application will start to error.

A couple things I might consider are:

- how likely is google to change their API? Do they have a history of it, do they commit to a formal versioning scheme?
- is it possible to get a test account and keep your two integration tests.  Perhaps only run your integration tests 1x a day? Or only on master commits? Ideally a test account will give you enough quota to run your integration tests on every single build and locally.
- is it possible to save periodic google responses? Say every 12 hours?? You could have a background service that hits google maps for a success response and an error response and save that to a static file storage.  Then your test could pull it down before every run.  I feel like this might be an OK compromise between API request limits/rate limiting and freshness.  But would require the most work.

Nothing beats testing against the actual service, as often as possible, if it is doable.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the insight. As of right now, I have my unit test hitting the API, which I need to change. I like the idea of using a fixture to test the response, and then consistently checking to make sure nothing has changed in Google's response. Thanks for your help!